# User not logged in - session cookie too large?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, flask

I am following the authentication tutorial for google app engine/python here: https://cloud.google.com/python/getting-started/authenticate-users

I'm sure I've followed everything correctly, but when I click the login button on the page I am prompted to log in with google but then when redirected back to the page, it shows the user is not logged in.

I have checked the local server and it is saying:

```
UserWarning: The "session" cookie is too large: the value was 4755 bytes but the header required 26 extra bytes. The final size was 4781 bytes but the limit is 4093 bytes. Browsers may silently ignore cookies larger than this.
```

I am not 100% sure this is my problem, but it is the only thing that stands out to me. Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, all data needed to verify the authentication is in the cookie, and you are storing too much info in it.

You can reduce what is stored for the profile, perhaps, in the `_request_user_info()` hook:

```
def _request_user_info(credentials):
    # ...
    resp, content = http.request(
        'https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me')

    # ...
    session['profile'] = json.loads(content.decode('utf-8'))
```

Rather than store the *whole* dictionary, filter the dictionary that `json.loads()` returns and only retain the profile information your application really needs to have. That, or store this information somewhere else, like in memcached (so retrieve it each time you need it and it is not available in memcached still).

See the [*People resource* documentation](https://developers.google.com/+/web/api/rest/latest/people#resource) to see what data is being stored in `session['profile']` and pick what you really need. The tutorial, for example, only needs the display name and the image url:

```
profile = json.loads(content.decode('utf-8'))
session['profile'] = {'displayName': profile['displayName'], 'image': profile['image']}
```

Comment: Thanks, do you know how I can do this so it just retrieves a username and photo?

Comment: @user9109814: You mean the Google API call to load the profile? `https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me` will always return all data for the scope configured, it can't return less data. Just extract what you need and store that in the session.

Comment: I've just seen your edit, thanks but unfortunately the cookie is still too large.

Comment: @user9109814: So what is in the session dictionary now? Print it out, compare between methods. Does not storing anything in `profile` help?

Comment: Sorry but I don't know how to do that. I am trying to learn and these Google tutorials are garbage, I'm just going to leave it. Thank you for your help.