# Session cookie too large locally but works when deployed

Tags: python, google-app-engine, flask, oauth-2.0

I'm using flask_util for Google App Engine as described here: [Authenticating Users with Python](https://cloud.google.com/python/getting-started/authenticate-users).

When using the local dev server, I get the following warning after selecting a Google email on the auth page:

> /usr/local/google/home/pereyra/Desktop/chess/lib/werkzeug/wrappers.py:1116:
>   UserWarning: The "session" cookie is too large: the value was 4388
>   bytes but the header required 65 extra bytes. The final size was 4453
>   bytes but the limit is 4093 bytes. Browsers may silently ignore
>   cookies larger than this.   samesite=samesite

which results in a bad request: "Invalid request state". However, if I deploy my app, this works fine.

In a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47855364/user-not-logged-in-session-cookie-too-large), it was suggested filtering the response in _request_user_info, however, even making this empty doesn't seem to make a difference and the fact that it works when deployed suggests there is a better solution.

Comment: I have the same problem. If it helps, I have figured that the problem is that even if you delete the session['profile'] data, there are a lot more data stored in session. You can view those using session.get_items()
I have no idea how to delete those though